# SWF-Flash switch

Tags: html, flash, switch-statement

I want to showcase my company work to our future client.

The project which I am going to showcase is basically a FLASH-HTML5 conversion.

I want to use a switch on the page which will swap flash to HTML5 page and vice versa.

If I am on page3 of flash file and hit the switch button it should load page 3 from HTML5.

something similar to 'https://www.pixelplant.com/gallery/'

Can you guys help me out how to do it? What technology I should use?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. The example website uses iframe in a popup div, which could be done with jquery or any lightbox plugin based on jquery. You can also use inline hidden divs to fade-in/fade-out. 
The switch binds with a function to call the relevant divs to display, that's it.